# css Transforms on SVG elements - what's the math?

Tags: html, css, svg

When you do something like `transform: translateX(50px)` on an svg element, like a `<rect>` or something, does that 50px scale to the svg units or is it 50 on-screen pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, guess I have my answer

https://jsfiddle.net/oegmc7xt/

html:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve" width="200px">
  <rect fill="#444444" width="200" height="200"></rect>
  <rect fill="#abcdef" width="100" height="100" class="move"></rect>
</svg>


<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve" width="100px">
  <rect fill="#444444" width="200" height="200"></rect>
  <rect fill="#abcdef" width="100" height="100" class="move"></rect>
</svg>
```

css:

```
.move {
  transform: translateX(50px)
}
```

Seems like "50px" is scaling to 50 svg units

Comment: Even more, it is in [userspace coordinates](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#EstablishingANewUserSpace). That means that if several transforms are nested inside the svg, or a new viewport is established with a viewBox atribute, units are expressed in coordinates of the element with respect to the next parent transforming the coordinate system.